# SeekBar Holo theme changed

Tags: android, seekbar

I created 2 separate activities in each of one of the i added a seekbar 
The first SeekBar looks quite nice 
[image: normal]
But the second activity which is the exact duplicated from the first have this apperence
[image]
Whent i access the Graphical Layout of the xml file everything seems right.
I couldn't undrestand why the seekbar theme has changed, is that normal ? how can i fix that ?